# Is there Optimizations in the render pipeline for Virtual Reality

Tags: virtual-reality

Im trying to get my head around the render pipeline on a Head Mounted Display. 
Given that a we have a target refresh rate of 90hz per screen.

Is there efficiency built within the pipeline that benefit from a reduced compute load on the reduced delta from one frame to another in VR?
Im wondering does the fact that less pixels have changed in the image from Frame A to B @ 90fps compared to Frame A to B @ 45fps given the same movement on screen.

I.e is the workload per frame from moving 1 frame to another anyway reduced by these new frames.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV1DM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK all frames on VR HMDs are always rendered from scratch as in other 3d applications. If there was a good method to magically interpolate the rendering why would it only be used on VR?

There is however another trick called [Timewarp](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-timewarp-overview/). With proper async timewarp implementation if you don't provide a new frame in time, the last one is rotated by the delta of your headset rotation.
So when you look around, the head movement is still looking as if your 
app would have high fps.
If you were not moving and there is nothing "stuck" to the camera like a GUI, this is a very good ilusion.

Currently timewarp is working well on GearVR and Vive, possibly on production ready Oculus (but not on DK2 on 0.8 drivers, still haven't got my new headset).